# AVX2 integer multiply of signed 8-bit elements, producing signed 16-bit results?

Tags: c++, simd, avx, avx2

I have two __m256i vectors, filled with 32 8-bit integers. Something like this:

```
    __int8 *a0 = new __int8[32] {2};
    __int8 *a1 = new __int8[32] {3};

    __m256i v0 = _mm256_loadu_si256((__m256i*)a0);
    __m256i v1 = _mm256_loadu_si256((__m256i*)a1);
```

How can i multiply these vectors, using something like `_mm256_mul_epi8(v0, v1)` (which does not exist) or any another way?

I want 2 vectors of results, because the output element width is twice the input element width.  Or something that works similarly to `_mm_mul_epu32` would be ok, using only the even input elements (0, 2, 4, etc.)

Comment: you may see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193601/sse-multiplication-16-x-uint8-t

Comment: [`_mm256_mul_epi32` *does* exist.](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=_mm256_mul_epi32&expand=3651,3651,3651) Do you mean `_mm256_mul_epi8` ? Please also specify what sort of result you want: 16 bit ? Low order 8 bits ? High order 8 bits ? Saturated 8 bit result ?

Comment: @PaulR, sorry i really mean '_mm256_mul_epi8', which does not exist. I want to get 16 bit result, if possible.

Comment: I edited your question to be specific about signedness of inputs/outputs and include the detail from your comment.  Please edit again if anything I added isn't actually what you want.

Comment: The obvious way is to unpack to 16-bit elements (inconvenient for signed because of lane-crossing, but you could always unpack and use `vpmovsx`), and use `_mm256_mullo_epi16`.  You might also be able to use [`_mm256_maddubs_epi16`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/PMADDUBSW.html) with some masking to get odd/even elements, if you can deal with one input being unsigned and the other signed.  (`0*anything  + a*b` = `a*b`, so you have a widening multiply that just takes one AND instruction to set up for.)

Comment: @PeterCordes thank you, `_mm256_maddubs_epi16` is definitely what i need! (In my case all input is unsigned, now i see how can this detail be important)

Comment: @KaraUL: Read the docs *carefully*: `maddubs` takes one signed input, and one unsigned input.  If one of your unsigned inputs is limited range, like always 0..127, then you can use it as the signed input.

Answer (score 3):

You want the result separated in two vectors so this is my suggestion for your question. I've tried to be clear, simple and realizable:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <x86intrin.h>
 void _mm256_print_epi8(__m256i );
 void _mm256_print_epi16(__m256i );
 void _mm256_mul_epi8(__m256i , __m256i , __m256i* , __m256i* );


int main()
{
    char a0[32] = {1, 2, 3, -4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, -10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, -24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32};
    char a1[32] = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, -13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, -20, 21, 22, 23, 24, -25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33};

    __m256i v0 = _mm256_loadu_si256((__m256i*) &a0[0]);
    __m256i v1 = _mm256_loadu_si256((__m256i*) &a1[0]);

    __m256i r0, r1;//for 16 bit results

    _mm256_mul_epi8(v0, v1, &r0, &r1);

    printf("\nv0 = ");_mm256_print_epi8(v0);
    printf("\nv1 = ");_mm256_print_epi8(v1);
    printf("\nr0 = ");_mm256_print_epi16(r0);
    printf("\nr1 = ");_mm256_print_epi16(r1);
    printf("\nfinished\n");


    return 0;
}
//v0 and v1 are 8 bit input vectors. r0 and r1 are 18 bit results of multiplications
 void _mm256_mul_epi8(__m256i v0, __m256i v1, __m256i* r0, __m256i* r1)
{
    __m256i tmp0, tmp1;
    __m128i m128_v0, m128_v1;

    m128_v0 = _mm256_extractf128_si256 (v0, 0);
    m128_v1 = _mm256_extractf128_si256 (v1, 0);

    tmp0= _mm256_cvtepi8_epi16 (m128_v0); //printf("\ntmp0 = ");_mm256_print_epi16(tmp0);
    tmp1= _mm256_cvtepi8_epi16 (m128_v1); //printf("\ntmp1 = ");_mm256_print_epi16(tmp1);


    *r0 =_mm256_mullo_epi16(tmp0, tmp1);

    m128_v0 = _mm256_extractf128_si256 (v0, 1);
    m128_v1 = _mm256_extractf128_si256 (v1, 1);

    tmp0= _mm256_cvtepi8_epi16 (m128_v0); //printf("\ntmp0 = ");_mm256_print_epi16(tmp0);
    tmp1= _mm256_cvtepi8_epi16 (m128_v1); //printf("\ntmp1 = ");_mm256_print_epi16(tmp1);

    *r1 =_mm256_mullo_epi16(tmp0, tmp1);


}
 void _mm256_print_epi8(__m256i vec)
{
    char temp[32];
    _mm256_storeu_si256((__m256i*)&temp[0], vec);
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<32; i++)
        printf(" %3i,", temp[i]);


}

 void _mm256_print_epi16(__m256i vec)
{
    short temp[16];
    _mm256_storeu_si256((__m256i*)&temp[0], vec);
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<16; i++)
        printf(" %3i,", temp[i]);   
}
```

The output is:

```
[martin@mrt Stack over flow]$ gcc -O2 -march=native mul_epi8.c -o out
[martin@mrt Stack over flow]$ ./out

v0 =    1,   2,   3,  -4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9, -10,  11,  12,  13,  14,  15,  16,  17,  18,  19,  20,  21,  22,  23, -24,  25,  26,  27,  28,  29,  30,  31,  32,
v1 =    2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9,  10,  11,  12, -13,  14,  15,  16,  17,  18,  19, -20,  21,  22,  23,  24, -25,  26,  27,  28,  29,  30,  31,  32,  33,
r0 =    2,   6,  12, -20,  30,  42,  56,  72,  90, -110, 132, -156, 182, 210, 240, 272,
r1 =  306, 342, -380, 420, 462, 506, 552, 600, 650, 702, 756, 812, 870, 930, 992, 1056,
finished
[martin@mrt Stack over flow]$
```

**NOTE:** I've commented the intermediate results tmp0 and tmp1 in the recommended code.
In addition, as peter suggested in comments and provided a godbolt link, if your program loads from memory and you don't need to multiply elements in vectors you can use this code:

```
#include <immintrin.h>

//v0 and v1 are 8 bit input vectors. r0 and r1 are 18 bit results of multiplications
__m256i mul_epi8_to_16(__m128i v0, __m128i v1)
{
    __m256i tmp0 = _mm256_cvtepi8_epi16 (v0); //printf("\ntmp0 = ");_mm256_print_epi16(tmp0);
    __m256i tmp1 = _mm256_cvtepi8_epi16 (v1); //printf("\ntmp1 = ");_mm256_print_epi16(tmp1);

    return _mm256_mullo_epi16(tmp0, tmp1);
}

__m256i mul_epi8_to_16_memsrc(char *__restrict a, char *__restrict b){

    __m128i v0 = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*) a);
    __m128i v1 = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*) b);
    return mul_epi8_to_16(v0, v1);
}


int main()
{
    char a0[32] = {1, 2, 3, -4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, -10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, -24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32};
    char a1[32] = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, -13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, -20, 21, 22, 23, 24, -25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33};

    __m256i r0 = mul_epi8_to_16_memsrc(a0, a1);

}
```

Comment: You probably want to use 128-bit input vectors, so this can compile to `vpmovsxbw ymm0, [mem]` loads, and not bottleneck on the shuffle port from also unpacking with `_mm256_extractf128_si256`.  Also, that would let your helper function just return a single `__m256i`.

Comment: Some negative inputs would be good for your test-cases, to show that `_mm256_cvtepi8_epi16` is properly sign-extending, unlike unpacking with zero or using `_mm256_cvtepu8_epi16`

Comment: @PeterCordes, Hey Peter, actually I think using `vpmovsxbw` which the intrinsic is `__m256i _mm256_cvtepi8_epi16 (__m128i a)` on the elements that are presented in a vector might not be better than extraction. Because I have to write to cache and read from it again. Do I miss something?

Comment: Compilers can fold a `_mm_loadu_si128` into a memory source for `_mm256_cvtepi8_epi16`.  There's no store/reload.  https://godbolt.org/z/GyX-V7 is a version of your function with 128-bit inputs, and a wrapper that inlines it on the result of 2 loads.  The OP shows that they're loading from memory, so they don't already have `__m256i` vectors as a result of some calculation.