# how to vectorize blending two photos for screen formula?

Tags: c++, simd, intrinsics, blending, avx2

I am trying to make vectorization for this formula

```
res[i] = 255 - ((255 - img1[i]) * (255 - img2[i])) / 255;
```

I have already written the vectorization, but it seems not working correctly 
 about code:

1. load from memory using this _mm256_loadu_epi8
2. t = (255-img) subtract _mm256_subs_epu8(one_value_vector8, partImg1)
3. t * b for multiplication I used function suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52370634/avx2-integer-multiply-of-signed-8-bit-elements-producing-signed-16-bit-results) 
   here is the code

v0 and v1 are 8 bit input vectors. r0 and r1 are 18 bit results of multiplications

```
void _mm256_mul_epi8(__m256i v0, __m256i v1, __m256i* r0, __m256i* r1){
    __m256i tmp0, tmp1;
    __m128i m128_v0, m128_v1;

    m128_v0 = _mm256_extractf128_si256 (v0, 0);
    m128_v1 = _mm256_extractf128_si256 (v1, 0);

    tmp0= _mm256_cvtepi8_epi16 (m128_v0); //printf("\ntmp0 = ");_mm256_print_epi16(tmp0);
    tmp1= _mm256_cvtepi8_epi16 (m128_v1); //printf("\ntmp1 = ");_mm256_print_epi16(tmp1);


    *r0 =_mm256_mullo_epi16(tmp0, tmp1);

    m128_v0 = _mm256_extractf128_si256 (v0, 1);
    m128_v1 = _mm256_extractf128_si256 (v1, 1);

    tmp0= _mm256_cvtepi8_epi16 (m128_v0); //printf("\ntmp0 = ");_mm256_print_epi16(tmp0);
    tmp1= _mm256_cvtepi8_epi16 (m128_v1); //printf("\ntmp1 = ");_mm256_print_epi16(tmp1);

    *r1 =_mm256_mullo_epi16(tmp0, tmp1);
}
```

I am working with 8-bit unsigned integer but after the multiplication, I started to work with 16 bit since the result of multiplication is bigger than 255.
4. divByOne1 = (r0/255) then dividing using _mm256_div_epu16(r0, one_value_vector16);
5. partRes = 255 - divByOne get the last result using same like 1 _mm256_subs_epu16
6. store the result back res[i + j] = partRes1.m256i_u16[j];

the result of vectorization differs from the needed one at some indexes here is an example

```
2
5 
8 
11 
14 
 0 
 3 
 6 
 9 
 12
 15
 1 
 4 
 7 
 10
 13
 2 
 5 
 8 
 11
 14
```

strangely enough, these indexes get repeated so maybe I have a problem with loading the pixels.

my full code

```
std::vector<unsigned char> vectorizedImplementation(const std::vector<unsigned char>& img1, const std::vector<unsigned char>& img2)
{
    std::vector<unsigned char> res(img1.size());

    __m256i  partImg1, partImg2, partRes1, partRes2;
    int vari = 32;
    int partSize = res.size() / vari * vari;
    //255 - ((255-Target) * (255-Blend))/255
    __m256i one_value_vector16 = _mm256_set_epi16(255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, `255,`
        255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255);
    __m256i one_value_vector8 = _mm256_set_epi8(255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
        255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
        255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255);

    //https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/874396/Crunching-Numbers-with-AVX-and-AVX
    for (int i = 0; i < partSize; i += vari) {
        partImg1 = _mm256_loadu_epi8(&img1[i]);
        partImg2 = _mm256_loadu_epi8(&img2[i]);

        // t = (255-img)     , b = (255-img) 
        __m256i t = _mm256_subs_epu8(one_value_vector8, partImg1);//122*201>255
        __m256i b = _mm256_subs_epu8(one_value_vector8, partImg2);
        //r0 = t * b  , r1 = t * b 
        __m256i r0, r1;//for 16 bit results
        _mm256_mul_epi8(t, b, &r0, &r1);//function from the link provided above
        //divByOne1 = (r0/255) , divByOne2 = (r1/255)
        __m256i divByOne1 = _mm256_div_epu16(r0, one_value_vector16);
        __m256i divByOne2 = _mm256_div_epu16(r1, one_value_vector16);
        //partRes = 255 - divByOne
        partRes1 = _mm256_subs_epu16(one_value_vector16, divByOne1);
        partRes2 = _mm256_subs_epu16(one_value_vector16, divByOne2);

        int j = 0;
        for (; j < vari/2; j++) {
            res[i + j] = partRes1.m256i_u16[j];
        }
        int k = 0;
        for (; j < vari; j++,k++) {
            res[i + j] = partRes2.m256i_u16[k];
        }

    }
    return res;
}
```

here is my code results against the required one
[image: my code results]
[image: correct resutls]

Comment: For a 50:50 blend, you can use `_mm256_avg_epu8` (`vpavgb`) https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pavgb:pavgw.  But your multiply formula is I think a different kind of blending.

Comment: Note that `_mm256_div_epu16` isn't an intrinsic for a single hardware instruction, and is presumably *very* slow compared to using a multiplicative inverse manually, or some other trick for the special case of div by 255.

Comment: Your "link above" points to your result image. You need to make your question self-contained. As Peter said, `_mm256_div_epu16` is not an intrinsic, instead you should multiply by `0x8081` and shift by 23. And at the end, do not manually mix together both halves like that (ideally, your 16bit vectors would be split in even and odd results).

Comment: I see that you fixed the link (and I could have guessed that from the name): The given `_mm256_mul_epi8` implementation does **signed** 8 bit multiplication, which obviously gives strange results with unsigned inputs.

Comment: @chtz after search, didn't find something like _mm256_mullo_epu16, how to make the multiplication works only on the unsigned representation of the numbers?

Comment: Did you find this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193601/sse-multiplication-16-x-uint8-t (you need to divide by 255 before casting back to 8 bit, of course)

Comment: For dividing by 255 check Peter's answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/35286833/6870253